# How to remove selected/highlighted cell in UICollectionView in another View Controller for Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm using a UICollectionView which only allows a single selection. The current issue I'm facing is that even after pressing other tabs/buttons to segue to another view controller, the highlighted cell still remains. What I want to do is that when I click other tabs that shows another view controller, the highlighted cell automatically gets unhighlighted.

The following is my code:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false


    collectionView.allowsSelection = true
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    if previouslySelected != nil{
        if let previousCell =  collectionView.cellForItem(at: previouslySelected!){
            previousCell.layer.borderWidth = 0
            previousCell.layer.borderColor = .none
        }
    }

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.borderWidth = 0
    cell?.layer.borderColor = .none
    if previouslySelected != nil{
        if let previousCell =  collectionView.cellForItem(at: previouslySelected!){
            previousCell.layer.borderWidth = 0
            previousCell.layer.borderColor = .none
        }
    }


}
```

Edit: I have noticed that after pressing next and selecting other cells, the selected cell change but the previous cell is still highlighted(although it isn't selected anymore). Any idea on how to remove the highlight for the not selected cell?

Comment: Welcome SiYang! You can use the function collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true) to deselect a cell at a given indexPath

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing how I managed to solve it:

declare in `class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController`

```
var currentlySelected: Int?
var previouslySelected: IndexPath?
```

next, in cellForItemAt func,

```
if currentlySelected != nil && currentlySelected == indexPath.row
        {
            uploadPostButton.isEnabled = true
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        }
        else
        {
            cell.layer.borderColor = .none
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
        }
```

also in `didSelectItemAt`

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        if previouslySelected != nil{
            if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: previouslySelected!){
                cell.layer.borderColor = .none
                cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
            }
        }
        currentlySelected = indexPath.row
        previouslySelected = indexPath

        // For reload the selected cell
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])//this is to "refresh" the selection
```

so, it kind of achieve what I wanted, but I am sure there is a cleaner/better way that I would like to learn!